# Sharing Rule Calculations Missing Buttons

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule

I am missing the buttons on the Share Calculations (suspend, resume, recalc). How do I get these visible on the page?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need the "Manage Sharing Calculation Deferral" permission in order to view those buttons.

[Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_sharing_rule_recalculation.htm&type=5)